# Catalyst Template Toolkit template not found return 404

Tags: perl, http-status-code-404, catalyst, template-toolkit

I'm trying to create a [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/) app that is pretty flexible for my designers. By this I mean that if they need to add a new page with static content on it, I don't have to go into `Catalyst` and add that action before they can create a template for the page. I have it so that if they add any template named `name.html`, then the `Catalyst` app can display `http://www.domain.com/name.html` even without a `name` action. Currently I have a subroutine in the Root controller that looks like this:

```
sub any_template :Regex('(.+)\.html$') { 
    my ($self, $c) = @_; 
    $c->stash(
        template => $c->action . '.html',
    );
}
```

and this makes it so that any request ending with '.html' will look for a template by that name. However, if a url is requested for a template that does not exists, [Template Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/) throws an error saying that it could not render the template, which makes sense since it does not exist. However, I would like to instead be able to display my 404 not found page if a template does not exist. Is it possible to do this? Or does anyone have a better way to make it to where you can have template pages without having to add an empty action to your `Catalyst` app? I know that it could be possible to use perl's [-e](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) file test to see if the template exists on the filesystem, but are there any better ways to do it? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

This is what my current wrapper looks like:

```
[% 
    debug("Applying HTML page layout wrappers to $template.name\n");
    content WRAPPER "$host/site/html" + "$host/site/layout";
-%]
```

This was mostly generated by TTSite. Is there anyway I could do something similar to what RET was suggesting, where I could use a try catch block to use a 404 page if this fails?

**UPDATE**

I've tried updating my wrapper template to this:

```
[%- 
    TRY;
        content WRAPPER "$host/site/html" + "$host/site/layout"; 
    CATCH file;
        "File Error! $error.info";
    CATCH;
        "Error: $error.info!";
    END;
-%]
```

And it will say that there is a file error when it cannot find the page:

```
Couldn't render template test.html: file error - test.html: not found
```

However, it is not going to either of my catch blocks. Should I be putting it somewhere else?

**UPDATE**

The [Template Toolkit](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Directives.html#section_TRY_THROW_CATCH_FINAL) documentations says:

```
Note that the DEFAULT option (disabled by default) allows you to specify a default 
file to be used any time a template file can't be found. This will prevent file 
exceptions from ever being raised when a non-existant file is requested (unless,
of course, the DEFAULT file your specify doesn't exist). Errors encountered once 
the file has been found (i.e. read error, parse error) will be raised as file 
exceptions as per usual.
```

This is exactly what I am looking for, but there are no examples of how to use this. Does anyone know how to use the `DEFAULT` option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up figuring out a solution that allowed me to do what I wanted. Instead of using the default RenderView, I created my own:

```
#old end action
#sub end : ActionClass('RenderView') {}

sub end : Private { 
    my ($self, $c) = @_; 

    return if $c->res->body ne '';  

    my $output;
    eval { $output = $c->view($c->stash->{current_view})->render($c,$c->stash->{template})};

    unless($@) { 
        $c->res->body($output);
    }   
    else {
        $c->res->status(404);
        $c->stash->{template} = 'errors/404.html';
        $c->forward($c->view('NO_HTML'));
    }   
}
```

It is possibly a little bit hacky, but it does what I want and allows me to display a 404 page along with a response of 404 whenever a page is not found, and this allows me to keep the flexibility of not having to define an action for every template that I create.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need to use Catalyst at all for your static content. Usually, static content like images, CSS, Javascript is served directly by your web server (nginx or APache). You could do the same with your HTML static files.

If you really want to mix static and dynamic content, look at Catalyst::Plugin::Static::Simple][1](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Catalyst%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aStatic%3a%3aSimple) and the `$c->serve_static_file($file_path)` function.

Comment: but then I lose the benefit of having a templating system, where the only content that needs to be changed is in the middle of the page. I want my designers not to have to repeat the same header, footer, etc everywhere. So it is 'static' content, but really I still want to have the benefits of a templating system like Template Toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

I've upvoted Julien's answer, because he's exactly right - this is the best way to handle truly static resources. If it's just HTML, get them to put it in the static area and set up alias or location records as required for your web-server.

However, if your designers are producing templates that need to be put inside a `WRAPPER` or need some dynamic handling, you will quickly hit some limits with that approach.

Rather than process the template directly like that, you could do something like this:

**=== Root.pm ===**

```
sub any_template {
    ...
    $c->stash(template => 'static.tt');
}
```

**=== static.tt ===**

```
[%- WRAPPER foo.tt -%]
[%- SET tmpl = c.action;
    TRY;
        # use either PROCESS if a template, or INCLUDE if it's HTML
        PROCESS tmpl _ ".tt";
        # INCLUDE tmpl _ ".html"; # or this
    CATCH;
        PROCESS "404.tt";
    END -%]
[%- END -%]
```

So that the file-not-found is gracefully handled. Using a `404.tt` template means your wrapper's header/footer etc is still presented.

Comment: is there anyway I could get `404.tt` to display without the same header and footer?

Comment: I've made an update to my post above showing my current wrapper code. Is there any way I could do something similar to what you do here in your example to process 404.tt if there is an error?

Comment: You cannot put this logic into the wrapper, because `content` is generated first, and then the wrapper - it's inside out by design. So your failed template render has already happened. In answer to your question about changing the header/footer on a 404, just set a variable inside 404.tt that you test for in the wrapper. Or put a different `WRAPPER` inside the `CATCH` block.